# How to search for list of papers citing both papers A and B?

Tags: publications, citations, online-resource, literature-search, google-scholar

For given papers A and B, I would like to search for all papers that cite both A and B. I guess one can generalize to papers {A,B,C,...} and find all papers that cite all of them.

A quick Google Scholar and Web of Science search revealed nothing. Google Scholar has a "cite=..." thing in the URL, which I messed with a bit to no avail.

Comment: I think this would be a useful tool. I found a [thread on Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/jH1L3KjssZk) where someone suggested this, but I don't think Google has yet implemented such a tool.

Answer (score 8):

Just get the citations of each document from the Scopus database, export the results into two files, and write a Python script that does a set intersection. You can generalize this to any files.

You can export the Scopus results to .csv files, and then use the `csv` python module to read the files. You can then have the set operation based on the title of the articles (even though I would also export the DOI and use it). If you know how to program in Python, writing this script shouldn't take you more than one afternoon.

Comment: +1, even though Scopus is horribly incomplete.  If only Google Scholar had an API (or didn't cut you off for screen-scraping).

Answer (score 5):

In Wikidata, we have at the moment around 36 million citations. It is not much compared to Google Scholar, but you can query them in flexible ways with the Wikidata Query Service, - a SPARQL endpoint.

In Scholia, a website that uses Wikidata Query Service, we have implemented a query that shows "all papers that cite both A and B". You can see an example for "Protein measurement with the Folin phenol reagent" and "Novel method for detection of beta-lactamases by using a chromogenic cephalosporin substrate" here: https://tools.wmflabs.org/scholia/works/Q20900776,Q24564458.

Scholia will also show results for more than two papers, see, e.g., https://tools.wmflabs.org/scholia/works/Q20900776,Q24564458,Q39309940.

Following the link "Edit on query.Wikidata.org" gets you to the SPARQL query at the Wikidata Query Service interface. The SPARQL query currently reads:

```
SELECT ?date ?work ?workLabel
WITH {
  SELECT (MIN(?dates) AS ?date) ?work 
  WHERE {
    ?work wdt:P2860 wd:Q20900776 .  ?work wdt:P2860 wd:Q24564458 . 
    OPTIONAL {
      ?work wdt:P577 ?datetimes .
      BIND(xsd:date(?datetimes) AS ?dates)
    }
  }
  GROUP BY ?work
  ORDER BY DESC(?date)
  LIMIT 1000
} AS %results
WHERE {
  INCLUDE %results
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en,da,es,fr,nl,no,ru,sv,zh". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?date)
```

You can read more about the approach of using Wikidata and SPARQL for citation analysis work in this paper: "Scholia and scientometrics with Wikidata", https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04222