# How to find all the articles citing particular two?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

It is quite easy given a single article to find all the articles citing it.

However, having two or more articles, how do I find all the articles simultaneously citing these?

Answer (score 0):

Using Google scholar, you can find the articles citing article #1.
Then, you click the box "Search within citing articles" and you do a research for article #2.

Edit: I just realized this question is a duplicate of [How to search for list of papers citing both papers A and B?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28164/how-to-search-for-list-of-papers-citing-both-papers-a-and-b?rq=1)

But I think my answer is far simpler.