# How to search for articles citing a certain combination of papers?

Tags: citations, google-scholar, literature-search

It is often the case that the proposal of a specific idea or approach to a problem (or whole field of research)  triggers a sequel of papers discussing and extending this idea. In this sequel there are papers (probably two or three) that are established as "basic", as points of reference. Each one of them may be usefull in more than one directions of research. However  the  whole set of "basic" papers is characteristic of the discussion.

In this perspective the most efficient way to follow an approach or school of research is to search for articles that cite these (two or three) "basic" papers.

However, according to [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28164/how-to-search-for-list-of-papers-citing-both-papers-a-and-b) question this option is not available, but one has to write some Python code.

That was a year ago.

Is there any new  user-friendly alternative?

Comment: So, did you search and what did you find? So we don't duplicate effort...

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! We would like to help you, but your question is not very clear. In addition to revising your question to incorporate the information that @SolarMike asked for, you could clarify what Google Scholar (which you included as a tag) has to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search in proper websites, like Science direct. Also, have a look at the ranking of the journal the article was published in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... sort of.  Use a custom search in Google with a combination of operators like exact terms, 'and', etc.  Not necessarily Google scholar. It will give general answers that can be used to get what you want.