# How to identify papers that cite two particular papers

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Using Google scholar, we can find the citation of a paper A.
Now I want to find papers that cite both paper A and paper B.
That is, I want to find the intersection of citations of paper A  and paper B.
How can I do this?

Comment: You make two lists and look for matches between both lists.

Comment: And yet another version of the same question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28164/958

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do that in an online interface; you would at least need to code some queries, [as is suggested here based on *Wikidata*/*Scholia*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/97266/120630). (Actually, it might be possible with [*CitationGecko*](https://www.citationgecko.com/), but it currently doesn't work well in my browser, so I cannot check - - it is just too slow.)

My personal approach would be one of using the [API of *OpenCitations*](https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1#/citations/%7Bdoi%7D). Here is an example code in *R* based on two DOIs as visible in the form of `https://w3id.org/oc/index/coci/api/v1/citations/[DOI]`:

```
library(jsonlite)

work1 <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citations/10.1017/s0020818313000337")

work2 <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1/citations/10.1177/1354066106067346")

citingworks <- intersect(work1$citing, work2$citing)
```

Then, `citingworks` lists 32 DOIs that have cited both `work1` and `work2`:

```
> citingworks
 [1] "10.1017/9781108644082"                 "10.1017/9781108644082.001"            
 [3] "10.1017/9781108644082.002"             "10.1017/9781108644082.003"            
 [5] "10.1017/9781108644082.004"             "10.1017/9781108644082.005"            
 [7] "10.1017/9781108644082.006"             "10.1017/9781108644082.007"            
 [9] "10.1017/9781108644082.008"             "10.1017/9781108644082.009"            
[11] "10.1017/9781108644082.010"             "10.1177/1354066119889401"             
[13] "10.1093/jogss/ogy021"                  "10.31338/uw.9788323542988"            
[15] "10.1080/13533312.2020.1753513"         "10.1080/13569775.2020.1795372"        
[17] "10.1007/978-3-030-51521-8_1"           "10.1007/978-3-030-51521-8_2"          
[19] "10.1080/13600826.2020.1828298"         "10.1057/s41268-018-0147-z"            
[21] "10.1146/annurev-polisci-040711-135425" "10.1111/pops.12616"                   
[23] "10.1093/isq/sqz055"                    "10.1093/isr/viy006"                   
[25] "10.1093/isr/viz002"                    "10.1017/s0260210516000176"            
[27] "10.1017/s026021051600019x"             "10.3384/cu.2000.1525.1572479"         
[29] "10.1177/1354066117745365"              "10.1163/24056006-12340008"            
[31] "10.1177/0010836716653161"              "10.1080/09662839.2018.1497985"
```

But note that *OpenCitation*'s the data sample is *CrossRef*, which is not the same as *Google Scholar*.